# How to Change Header application/octet-stream to image/jpg while uploading a file from android

Tags: android, http-post, multipartentity

I am uploading a file form sd card to server, for that i am using AndroidMultiPartEntity

but i have to change header **content-type** application/octet-stream to image/jpg defaultly it is taking **application/octet-stream**

**My Code:**

```
AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(new ProgressListener() {

                @Override
                public void transferred(long num) {

                    publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));

                }
            });
File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

entity.addPart("mediaImg", new FileBody(sourceFile));
totalSize = entity.getContentLength();

            httppost.setEntity(entity);
// Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

**I am using httpmime-4.3.6.jar for this**

**httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "image/jpg");**

i tried above one but it taking application/octet-stream

same problem
https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/issues/504